# Require module math to calculate sum any 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

1. Require module math
2. Use method `add` to calculate sum any 2 numbers
3. Log the results to the screen

`math.js`

```
var math = {
  add: function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
};
math.add(3,4);
module.exports = math;
```

`index.js`

```
var math = require('./math');

console.log(math);
```

I don't know where I'm wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the error? I tried the same code, and that worked!

Comment: @Kaushik `{ add: [Function: add] }`. And my link: https://repl.it/repls/WhisperedFocusedComputation

Comment: because the `math` is a module. if you want any result then do this `console.log(math.add(9,8));`

Comment: and if you want to use `add` directly then use this `var {add} = require('./math');
console.log(add(9,9));`

Comment: @Kaushik It worked. Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to print the module, so the result will be the module details.

Here is how you can use the module function

```
var math = require('./math');
console.log(math);
```

If you want to use the functions without the module name, you need do like this

```
var {add} = require('./math');
console.log(add(9,9));
```

this is known as [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[live demo](https://repl.it/repls/UnfoldedAffectionateProfessionals)